# Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(String)" because "dbConnection" is null (Mysql connection)

Tags: java, mysql

I'm getting this error **Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(String)" because "dbConnection" is null**

**at com.claim.classes.Connection.selectRecordsFromTable(Connection.java:24)
at com.claim.classes.Connection.main(Connection.java:12)**

Looking at my code, everything looks right so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. Below is the code for my Connection class and DbConnection class

**Connection.java**

```
    package com.claim.classes;

        import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
        import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Connection {

    
 public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{  
 selectRecordsFromTable();
 } 
 
 private static void selectRecordsFromTable() throws SQLException {

 Connection dbConnection = null;
 PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

 String selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM USER WHERE id = ?";

 try {
 dbConnection = (Connection) DbConnection.getConnection();
 preparedStatement = ((java.sql.Connection) dbConnection).prepareStatement(selectSQL);
 preparedStatement.setInt(1, 16);

 // execute select SQL statement
 ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

 while (rs.next()) {

   int id  = rs.getInt("id");          
          String email = rs.getString("email");
          String fname = rs.getString("first_name");
          String lname = rs.getString("lanst_name");

          //Display values
          System.out.print("\nID: " + id +"\nEmail: " + email+ "\nfirst name: " + fname+"\nlast Name: " + lname);          
       
 }

 } catch (SQLException e) {

 System.out.println(e.getMessage());

 } finally {

 if (preparedStatement != null) {
 preparedStatement.close();
 }

 if (dbConnection != null) {
 ((Statement) dbConnection).close();
 }

 }

 }
}
```

**DbConnection.java**

```
package com.claim.classes;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DbConnection{

// public Connection conn;
//static reference to itself
    private static DbConnection instance = new DbConnection();    
    public static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/root";
    public static final String USER = "root";
    public static final String PASSWORD = "root";
    public static final String DRIVER_CLASS = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"; 
     
    //private constructor
    private DbConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER_CLASS);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
     
    private Connection createConnection() {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {                  
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
            System.out.println("Connected to Database.");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Unable to Connect to Database.");
        }
        return connection;
    }   
     
    public static Connection getConnection() {
        return instance.createConnection();
    }
 
}
```

There was a related question on here but that person was having a different problem than me. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You named your class `Connection`. Don't do that. You want a `java.sql.Connection` not a `com.claim.classes.Connection` and your code is hard to follow on that basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have *horrible* exception handling and it is at the root of this problem.

The best way to handle an exception, is to just throw it onwards, especially if the exception is the kind of thing the method would obviously throw based not on its implementation but solely its specification (so, the name of it, and its parameter types, and its javadoc). A method named `createConnection`, in a class named `DbConnection`, obviously should be declared to `throws SQLException`. Thus, fix your createConnection method; it should be:

```
private Connection createConnection() throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
    System.out.println("Connected to Database.");
    return connection;
}
```

Note how much cleaner that is.

If that is not possible (either because you are overriding a method and therefore cannot add any checked exceptions, or the exception is due to an implementation detail and should not be exposed), then the next best thing is to rethrow it as a different exception:

```
private Connection createConnection() {
    try {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
        System.out.println("Connected to Database.");
        return connection;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot connect to database", e);
    }
}
```

To be clear, **that is bad design** here, this method should just be declared to throw SQLException, it's a fundamental part of interacting with DBs.

What you're doing is much, *much* worse:

It led to this problem, for starters. The primarily problem is twofold:

1. You're tossing out a lot of useful info. That `e` object has a stack trace, a type, a message, causes, and more. By catching it and then just printing some stuff to syserr and continuing, you've tossed all this useful info in the bin.
2. By continuing the code, your app is now in a state you never expected (in this case, `Connection connection;` is null and thus null is returned. This results in two subproblems:

2a. The actual problem now occurs in an irrelevant place: The problem is that your 'connect to the DB' call is failing, but because of your exception handler, now a problem occurs on a line that has nothing to do with this (namely, the line that tries to use the null reference)

2b. 'stack trace explosion' - because code continues, but the app is in a state you did not expect, *obviously* the app is going to throw some sort of exception real soon. If all your exception handling code is like this, that, too, will get swallowed and results in some `System.out` traffic, and the situation continues onwards. The effect is that 1 problem causes a hundred stack traces to be dumped to sysout, and they are all **completely irrelevant**, except for the first one.

That last bit happened to you. Here is the simple rule:

**You must never catch an exception unless you will actually handle it OR rethrow it or some other exception from the catch block. System.err is NOT TO BE CALLED in them**.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. All I had to do was update my pom.xml file to include postgresql as a dependency - but that is if your are using maven as your project dependency management tool. See below.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

versions might differ with time.

I hope that helps